# inconsistent types in google earth engine with Export.image.toDrive()

Tags: export, google-earth-engine, landsat-7

I have computed [NDVI from Landsat7 image](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_api_06), but when I want to export the result in google drive with `Export.image.toDrive()` it failed with the message error : Fail with an error : `Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64.`

How can I overpass this issue ?

```js
/*-------------------------------------------------------------
                             FUNCTION
-------------------------------------------------------------*/

// This function adds a band representing the image timestamp.
var addTime = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(image.metadata('system:time_start')
    .divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365));
};

// COMPUTE NDVI OVER A COLLECTION FUNCTION
var addNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['B4', 'B3']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};


/*-------------------------------------------------------------
                             END
-------------------------------------------------------------*/

//2001
var img2001 = ee.Image("LANDSAT/LE7_L1T/LE72040492001066EDC00").clip(zone_travail);

var withNDVI = addNDVI(img2001).select('NDVI');
var withNDVI = addTime(withNDVI);

print(withNDVI);


/*------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                  SAVE DATA IN MY DRIVE 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/


Export.image.toDrive({
  image: withNDVI,
  description: 'ls7_ndvi_2001',
  scale: 30,
  region: zone_travail
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast the whole darn thing to a 32-bit float: `withNDVI.float()`.  Of course, make sure you're not getting any overflow, but looks safe here.

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that you are attempting to export two bands that have different data datatypes (float vs. double):

[image]

and because the format of the output file (GeoTIFF) does not (at least in practice) support mixing data types, because the [libtiff library does not support it](https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/gdal-dev/2010-August/025657.html). Given this, Earth Engine does not support exporting images with mixed band types.

The solution, as Nicholas suggests, is to make sure that all of the exported bands have a consistent data type. This is probably best accomplished by using [ee.Image.float()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagefloat) to convert your "time" band into a float:

```js
var addTime = function(image) {
  return image.addBands(
    image.metadata('system:time_start')
      .divide(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365).float()
      .rename('time')
    );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Nicholas' answer is spot on, but if you want to be sure of avoiding any overflow issues then you could cast as a 64-bit float instead: `withNDVI.toDouble()`.  This could be potentially be important with some images.