# Export filtered ImageCollection in Google Earth Engine to drive

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2

I want to export a filtered Sentinel2 composite to the drive, but I get an error message.

> *Error: Exported bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64.*

In the topic [inconsistent types in google earth engine with Export.image.toDrive()](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264239/inconsistent-types-in-google-earth-engine-with-export-image-todrive) it is stated, that GEE does not support exporting images with mixed band types for the GeoTIFF format. It is suggested to use [ee.Image.float()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimagefloat). But since I have an ImageCollection, I can not use this.

How do I convert all bands of a ImageCollection into float?

https://code.earthengine.google.com/cbcdaa0858e647504b85907857fe738c

```js
// Define Region of Interest (ROI) for filtering the Sentinel data 
var ROI = /* color: #0b4a8b */ee.Geometry.Polygon([
      [36.5048217773437, 0.560293804172086],
      [37.9302978515625, 0.560293804172086],
      [37.9302978515625, 1.875580463973453],
      [36.5048217773437, 1.875580463973453]
  ]);
Map.centerObject(ROI,8);  

// Define temporal space to collect data from
// Dry Seasons Kenya January-February and June-August
// Define the maximum cloudiness of the pictures for later masking

var startdate = '2016-01-01'; // first image year-month-day
var enddate = '2017-12-31'; // last image year-month-day
var calendar = 'month'; // month','day_of_year' 
var startshortdry = 1; // start month of first season
var endshortdry = 2; // end month of first season
var startlongdry = 6; // start motnh of second season
var endlongdry = 8; // end moonth of second season
var startshortwet = endshortdry+1; // start month of first season
var endshortwet = startlongdry-1; // end month of first season
var startlongwet = endlongdry+1; // start motnh of second season
var endlongwet = 12; // end month of second season
var cloudiness = 5; // cloudiness in %

// Import Sentinel data representing the ROI as ImageCollectoin and filter by date
var s2_ROIData = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2')
  .filterBounds(ROI)
  .filterDate(startdate, enddate)
  .filter(ee.Filter.or(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startshortdry, endshortdry, calendar),
  ee.Filter.calendarRange(startlongdry, endlongdry, calendar)))
  .map(function(image) {return image.clip(ROI);})
  .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE', cloudiness)
  );

// Convert the collection to a list and get the number of images
var count = s2_ROIData.size();
print('Number of filtered images in the region of interest: ', count);

// Function to remove clouds from the image collection. 
// The function uses the Sentinel-2 QA60 Band, 
// where bit10 represents clouds and bit11 represents cirrus
// Flags set to 0 indicating clear conditions. Returns masked and scaled data
   function ROIData_cloudmask(image) {
  var qa60 = image.select('QA60');
  var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int();
  var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();
  var mask =     qa60.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitMask).eq(0).and(qa60.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0));
return image.updateMask(mask).divide(10000);
  }

// Function to calculate MSAVI 
// MSAVI = (2*NIR+1-√((2*NIR+1)^2 - 8*(NIR-RED)))/2 
// MSAVI2 = (B08 + 1) - 0.5 * sqrt((2 * B08 - 1) ^ 2 + 8 * B04)) other Formula
    //     http://wiki.landscapetoolbox.org/doku.php/remote_sensing_methods:modified_soil-adjusted_vegetation_index
function ROIData_addMSAVI(input) {
      var msavi = input.select('B8').multiply(2).add(1)
      .subtract(input.select('B8').multiply(2).add(1).pow(2)
      .subtract(input.select('B8').subtract(input.select('B4'))
      .multiply(8)).sqrt()).divide(2)
      .rename('MSAVI');
   return input.addBands(msavi);
  }

// Function to calculate the Bare Soil Index BSI of the collection
//BSI = {(B11+B4)-(B8+B2)}/{(B11+B4)+(B8+B2)}
function ROIData_addBSI(input) {
  var bsi = input.select('B11').add(input.select('B4'))
      .subtract(input.select('B8').add(input.select('B2')))
          .divide(input.select('B1').add(input.select('B4')).add(input.select('B8')).add(input.select('B2')))
      .rename('BSI');
return input.addBands(bsi);
  }

// Function to calculate NDVI of the collection
// NDVI = (NIR - RED) / (NIR + RED), where RED is B4 and NIR is B8
// Values of 1 show vegetation, 0 bare and -1 water
function ROIData_addNDVI(input) {
  var ndvi = input.normalizedDifference(['B8', 'B4']).rename('NDVI');
return input.addBands(ndvi);
  }

// Pre-filter the composit for less cloudy granules and take the median
var ROIData_composite = s2_ROIData
  .map(ROIData_cloudmask)
  .map(ROIData_addMSAVI)
  .map(ROIData_addBSI)
  .map(ROIData_addNDVI)
  .median();

// Display cloudfree composit and Indices of the ROI 
// Values on Indices rangeing from -1 to 1, min and max adjusted for better visualization
//Map.addLayer(ROIData_composite, {bands:['MSAVI'], min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ['blue','white', 'green']}, 'MSAVI');
//Map.addLayer(ROIData_composite, {bands:['BSI'], min: -0.5, max: 0.5, palette: ['blue','white', 'red']}, 'BSI');
Map.addLayer(ROIData_composite, {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], min: 0, max: 0.2},'Cloudfree');

// Export the ROI satellite imagery in the Tasks tab
 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ROIData_composite,
  description: 'Sentinel2_Composite',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  region: ROI,
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are not exporting an ImageCollection but a single image. `ROIData_composite` is the median image of the ImageCollection `s2_ROIData`.

You can use `.float()` in your export statement and the export works:

```js
// Export the ROI satellite imagery in the Tasks tab
 Export.image.toDrive({
  image: ROIData_composite.float(),
  description: 'Sentinel2_Composite',
  scale: 10,
  maxPixels: 3784216672400,
  region: ROI,
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I did not think the solution would be so simple :)